# Easymock: Issue Mocking void DAO method - Unexpected method call

Tags: easymock

**Found a workaround. See solution at the bottom**

Ok I have been in EasyMock jail all day and I need some help getting out.
I have a void save() method I am mocking out.

```
public void save(PurchaseOrder po);
```

PurchaseOrder is an abstract class that has two children

```
USPurchaseOrder
CAPurchaseOrder
```

Here's my code in the JUnit test

```
MyDAO myDAO = createMock(MyDAO.class);
PurchaseOrder usPurchaseOrder = new USPurchaseOrder(msgUS);
myDAO.save(usPurchaseOrder);
expectLastCall().atLeastOnce();

PurchaseOrder caPurchaseOrder = new CAPurchaseOrder(msgCA);
myDAO.save(caPurchaseOrder);
expectLastCall().atLeastOnce();

replay(myDAO);

//execute code that uses DAO
```

I get the following error: Unexpected method call MyDAO.save(USPurchaseOrder@1a70b8):

The only problem here is that the DAO signature does not require a USPurchaseOrder, only a PurchaseOrder, which is what I am passing in.

Even doing this produces the same error

```
myDAO.save(new USPurchaseOrder(msgUS));
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Workaround**
Ok, I kept plugging away at this and while I don't understand why I am getting the error, I added the anyObject() to the code to get it to work.

```
MyDAO myDAO = createMock(MyDAO.class);

myDAO.save(anyObject(OrderRequest.class));

myDAO.save(anyObject(OrderRequest.class));

replay(myDAO);

//execute code that uses DAO
```

Answer (score 0):

For matching method calls EasyMock uses `equals()` for method parameters. You should take it into account. So my guess is that you have not implemented `equals()` in your `USPurchaseOrder` and the default `Object.equals()` behavior is used, that compares whether the instances of `USPurchaseOrder` are the same, which are apparently not.